# Creat a global variable from an argument and being able to use it as a numeric input

Tags: string-manipulation

I want something like this:

```
myfun[j_]:=Block[ {ans},
    ans = Range[j];
    "phi"<>ToString[j] = Total[ans];
];
```

The procedure is just an illustrative example.

Use it like this:

```
myfun[8]
```

return a Global variable `phi8` with value 36.

Similarly, myfun[j] return a Global variable `phij` with corresponding values.

Is that something possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```
myfun[j_] := 
  Block[{ans = Range[j]}, 
  ToExpression["phi" <> ToString[j] <> " = " <> ToString@Total[ans]]
];

myfun[10];
phi10
```

> 55

Comment: I think this `phi10=55` is just a string instead of a Global variable `phi10`? I have not yet tried it, but will do that asap.

Comment: You're right, I forgot the `ToExpression` call. I updated my answer.

Comment: Very nice trick! Thanks!